# How to keep the setPasswordPath config when reset password link is expired?

Tags: config, password, link

In **config.php** file, `setPasswordPath` is set to match a custom template. This is working fine by following the reset password link sent by email (for a front end user).

But after I've changed the password (with `users/setPassword` action), if I click again on the reset password link in the email, I am redirected to a page within the default Craft template that inform me that the verification code is now wrong.

How can I also set a custom template for this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the [invalidUserTokenPath](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#invalidUserTokenPath) config setting is what you're looking for.